# Getting the class name of selector clicked in JQuery ContextMenu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using JQuery's ContextMenu.

So I have the following code:

```
 $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.item-context, .nitem-context', 
        callback: function(key, options) {
            // CM.InventoryDetails.context_action(key, options);
            IM.Events.attach(IM.Events.events_const.ITEM_CONTEXT_ACTION,key,options);
        },
        items: {
            "view": {name: "View", icon: 'view'},
            "remove": {name : "Remove", icon: 'delete'},
        }
    });
```

My question is, how can I know the classname of the selector which triggered the event?

Your responses will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try with this in your callback function:

```
var className = options.items[key].$node[0].className;
```

Hope this helps.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Assign the class name and element and then user

```
e.delegateTarget.classList
```

you will be able to identify class and then process accordingly